# Grails 3 does not auto reload changes in my app

Tags: grails

I'm starting with grails 3 using the Intelijdea IDE but I'm having a problem and it's that when I'm in development stage my app does not auto reload the changes made which I find a bit problematic ..
If anyone knows please help me with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using grails 3.3.9 and had the same problem until I tried running my app with:

```
gradlew bootRun
```

And it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using grails 3.2.4 and auto reloading works fine. Only thing I noticed is that sometimes new methods don't get reloaded properly and will require a restart.

Maybe posting your exact grails and environment , version and details will help.

Comment: Currently is changed to version 3.2.6 and so far still no recharge, I do not understand why .. I have several app in 2.4.4 and these if compiled immediately

Comment: Auto reloading is not working in 3.2.9. New controller not reloaded, new actions not reloaded

Comment: solve the problem with the name change of my folder containing the project ... this time a name that had spaces ... since quite the spaces everything started to work well